# Extremely Wrong Battery Life

Tags: windows-8.1, dell-inspiron, battery-life

I am running Windows 8.1 on my Dell Inspiron 15", and when I click on the battery icon, it shows an outrageous battery life, which makes no sense: like 58 hours and 44 minutes (42% remaining).

How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Take the battery out and drop it a few times?

Comment: Have you tried to change the power plan? Is it the same estimation on all power plans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be from how Windows is making the predictions of battery life; it bases it off the current use. For example, on my laptop, if I am just looking through text files, it might say that I have 7 hours of battery life, when I have 40%. But then if I run a game, it drops to something like 2 hours. So what you are experiencing might just be temporary, and that your computer isn't doing much when the estimate was made. Just run your computer for a while (on battery), and see if it becomes more accurate.